# Azure: Web Service showing default screen and not code

Tags: node.js, azure

Followed this tutorial and did all the steps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs

For some reason, when I load the page, it shows a default "Hey, Node Developers" page, instead of the expected output "hello world". I am using a Linux server.

The code is on Azure's machine, but it is running the default page instead.

Any reasons why this might be?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I was uploading a folder with the desired repo inside of it, instead of the repo itself.